# How to fix a separation wall in the bathroom

Tags: bathroom, wood

We have a wooden part in the wall in the shower, which used to pass laundry (I think) from the bathroom to the service area as can be seen in the image bellow.

The water from the shower and the humidity doesn't help keep the wood from catching mold and breaking down.

We previously smoothed the wood and applied new paint, but the wood deteriorated back to its previous condition.

Any advice on how to have a permanent fix? Or should we simply consider removing it and finding a different solution?

[image]

An image of it from the other side:

[image]

Comment: ARE THOSE DRAWERS OR A CABINET WITH THE LAUNDRY SHOOT BELOW?

Comment: @JACK there are no drawers, just an empty space, also I saw the bottom left side for the cats to go out to their litter. I'm adding an image of the other side as well

Comment: And the window opens up into the laundry room?

Comment: Once wood is that far gone, it's hard to repair it, and the good portions of the wood are just going to have a similar fate sooner or later.  If you decide to try and save it, you need to manage the humidity in there.

Comment: @JACK yes the window opens to the laundry room

Comment: @JPhi1618 the humidity is a repeating issues, specially in the winter. We are considering trying to take it completely, or trying to cover it up with ceramics.

Comment: That plywood is delaminating your best plan is to replace it and prime and seal it with quality paint prior to installing it. If the new stuff is sealed including the edges it can withstand even occasional water spray but once plywood starts coming apart there is no way to seal it